# Uncaught TypeError EmberJS initializer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

So I was following this tutorial on authentication in EmberJS and when I added the initializer shown on that page it breaks my app.

This is the code that breaks the application

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'currentUser',

  initialize: function(container) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main');
    var user = App.User.find('current');

    container.lookup('controller:currentUser').set('content', user);
    container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'controller:currentUser');
  }
});
```

This is the error that happens

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    if (!wasApplied) {
      Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
    }
    o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
    o_defineProperty(this, '_super', undefinedDescriptor);
    var m = meta(this), proto = m.proto;
    m.proto = this;
    if (initMixins) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var mixins = initMixins;
      initMixins = null;
      this.reopen.apply(this, mixins);
    }
    if (initProperties) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var props = initProperties;
      initProperties = null;

      var concatenatedProperties = this.concatenatedProperties;

      for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
        var properties = props[i];

        Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports mixing in other definitions, use createWithMixins instead.", !(properties instanceof Ember.Mixin));

        for (var keyName in properties) {
          if (!properties.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) { continue; }

          var value = properties[keyName],
              IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING;

          if (IS_BINDING.test(keyName)) {
            var bindings = m.bindings;
            if (!bindings) {
              bindings = m.bindings = {};
            } else if (!m.hasOwnProperty('bindings')) {
              bindings = m.bindings = o_create(m.bindings);
            }
            bindings[keyName] = value;
          }

          var desc = m.descs[keyName];

          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties.", !(value instanceof Ember.ComputedProperty));
          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.", !(typeof value === 'function' && value.toString().indexOf('._super') !== -1));
          Ember.assert("`actions` must be provided at extend time, not at create time, when Ember.ActionHandler is used (i.e. views, controllers & routes).", !((keyName === 'actions') && Ember.ActionHandler.detect(this)));

          if (concatenatedProperties && indexOf(concatenatedProperties, keyName) >= 0) {
            var baseValue = this[keyName];

            if (baseValue) {
              if ('function' === typeof baseValue.concat) {
                value = baseValue.concat(value);
              } else {
                value = Ember.makeArray(baseValue).concat(value);
              }
            } else {
              value = Ember.makeArray(value);
            }
          }

          if (desc) {
            desc.set(this, keyName, value);
          } else {
            if (typeof this.setUnknownProperty === 'function' && !(keyName in this)) {
              this.setUnknownProperty(keyName, value);
            } else if (MANDATORY_SETTER) {
              Ember.defineProperty(this, keyName, null, value); // setup mandatory setter
            } else {
              this[keyName] = value;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    finishPartial(this, m);
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    m.proto = proto;
    finishChains(this);
    sendEvent(this, "init");
  } has no method 'find'
```

Comment: what page? and what version of ember.js are you using?

Comment: I only have the Index page and it's where it's happening. I'm running EmberJS 1.0.0 (latest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ember-data 1.0.0-beta the `DS.Model` subclasses like your `App.User`, doesn't have a `find` method. Instead you have to use:

- `store.find('user');` to find all data
- `store.find('user', id);` to find by id
- `store.find('user', { key: name });` to find by query

The result is the following:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'currentUser',

  initialize: function(container) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main');
    var user = store.find('user','current');

    container.lookup('controller:currentUser').set('content', user);
    container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'controller:currentUser');
  }
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hey Márcio, could you please point at some documentation related to that? Official docs here (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) are claiming that find is still there. And I don't get who should emit this initializer me or extension (i.e. Ember Data)?